# Access endpoint in one docker container from another

Tags: docker, curl

I have a docker-compose file with two services: `app` and `httpd`

#### app

```
app:
    image: primus852/machinelearning:latest
    ports:
        - 5001:5000
    expose:
        - "5001"
    restart: always
    networks:
        - default
    volumes:
        - ./api:/app
    environment:
        - FLASK_APP=app/source/__init__.py
        - FLASK_ENV=development
```

#### httpd

```
httpd:
  image: primus852/mitswiki:latest
  ports:
    - 80:80
  restart: always
  networks:
    - default
  volumes:
    - ./project:/var/www/html
```

#### Flask app

The `app` container has an endpoint like this:

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET'])
def predict():
    ...DO STH....
```

I can open `http://localhost:5001/predict` in my browser, works...
I can curl from my `cmd`: `curl localhost:5001/predict`, works...

But when I am inside my `httpd` container this does not work from the console: `curl localhost:5001/predict`

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5001: Connection refused

So I thought I address the `app` container as I address my mysql from inside my `httpd` container: `curl app:5001/predict` but it has the same result.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I do... It says in the very first sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your **yaml**:

```
ports:
    - 5001:5000
```

Inside container you have to use port `5000`

Comment: This pointed me to the right direction that I had to use the container port (the second) instead of the host (the first) port

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `httpd` container `localhost` refers to just that `httpd` container. It cannot access other containers by default.

Another thing which might be occuring is that your app is not open for 'remote' access. A connection from one container to another one is a remote connection.

Within your docker-compose files you can [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) containers to eachother

While the containers are linked you can then use curl to get the `/predict` page by using `curl app:5001/predict`